# When can I safely unplug an external drive on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, usb-drive, external-hdd, udisks, umount

I have browsed several answers... but none seems to address my question.

As reported in [bug #1067876](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1067876) the options to "safely remove" an external drive is gone.

No problem! Umount is sufficient for me. However, I cannot recognize WHEN it is safe to pull the USB plug out since the icon for the storage device does not disappear, and no notification is displayed. How can I know if it is safe to unplug the device? How can I explain to my mother when it is safe to do so? So I am looking for an *easy* solution (as it is present in 12.04).

Comment: I know that I can take a look with [Gnome Disks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/), or check in a terminal with 'mount'. Ubuntu is supposed to be user-friendly. Ejecting external drives is daily business. It cannot be possible that users have to use special software or terminal commands to check if they can safely unplug a device.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a BASH script on the Desktop might suffice until the bug is fixed.
This solution is from [Nikunj Lahoti](http://nikunjlahoti.com/2012/11/09/missing-safely-remove-in-ubuntu-12-10/). The software, udisks, can unmount and power down an external hard drive.

`sudo apt-get install udisks`

Then create a file (safelyremove.sh, perhaps) on the Desktop or a convenient place. Change /dev/sdc to your device. Make sure to include all partitions on the device.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Unmounting..."
udisks --unmount /dev/sdc1
udisks --unmount /dev/sdc2

echo "Spinning down..."
udisks --detach /dev/sdc

read -p "Done! Press [Enter] to exit."
```

Make the script executable. It will wait for [Enter] so you can see it is done.